# A market manager is expected to negotiate with their equivalent in power and authority in business settings/a setting - difference in meaning?

Tags: meaning, singular-vs-plural

**Example 1**

> A market manager is expected to negotiate with their equivalent in power and authority in a business **setting**.

**Example 2**

> A market manager is expected to negotiate with their equivalent in power and authority  in business **settings**.

What is the difference between using the singular form and using the plural form here?

Comment: Do you see a difference between these two sentences: "*A teacher is someone who teaches in **a school***" and "*A teacher is someone who teaches in **schools***"? It's the same thing.

Comment: Both are okay, although I would question whether it's necessary to have either of them. What's wrong with just "A market manager is expected to negotiate with their equivalent in power and authority"? Obviously this is going to be in a business setting.

Answer (score 1):

They sort of mean the same thing, but in the first case:

"a business setting"

is interpreted to mean "in any arbitrary business setting".

The second one *could* be interpreted to mean "in some, or many, but *possibly not all* business settings".

As it is intuitively clear that the second is not what is required, it is the first which would usually be used.